# When dealing with chemical data, is there a good way to deal with the < or > symbols in front of a number?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following plot code to plot nitrate data contained in a pandas dataframe. Within that dataframe is a column that contains nitrate data. Some of the data is recorded as <.2 for example, indicating that this value was below the detection limit. Is there a way to deal with this type of data or is it about simply removing the operand. The values with operands can be plotted as the type int or float without the operand.

[image]

Comment: If the label is a float, but the data are technically not continuous (i.e. you can have a value of 0.04 or 0.94, but not the infinite values in between) you can maintain the labels, but reorder them using a categoricalDtype that way it will know `'<0.02'` is smaller than `0.04`. That or just replace the labels with some arbitrary float that makes sense given the bounds.

Comment: Where is the plot code you are refering to?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes: it was in a linked image. I've edited the question to include it. I don't think users with lower rep can include photos.

Comment: @ALollz: Can you give me an example of code that would reorder the data?